# I can't explain the answer to this inequality, please help.

Tags: inequality

I had some issues explaining my answer in an inequality problem. I used a math-solving-program to get the end result, but I have no idea what it means or how to explain the answer with words.

The problem I had: Solve the inequality P(x) ≥ 0

where P(x) = x^(3)+2x^(2)-5x-6
The answer (end result) I got was this: X∈[-3,1] U [2,+∞>

But how do I explain this answer with words and what does this actually mean? Can someone please explain?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Shaun! I will also try to be more informative the next time I ask a question here :)

Comment: @TobiasRingsø You don't have to wait for next time, you can edit this question itself.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $x^3+2x^2-5x-6$ has 3 roots by the fundamental theorem of algebra. In this case the roots are real and have value -3, -1 and 2 (-1, not 1 as you say). You are looking for where this function is positive. Since it's continuous, it cannot change sign without crossing by zero right? (btw, this is Bolzano's theorem). So all you have to do is check all intervals
$(-\infty,-3],[-3,-1],[-1,2],[2,\infty)$.

Of course it's enough to check one since by continuity, the sign will be alternating in each consecutive interval. Doing so, you get the 2nd and the 4th intervals as you claim.